# Laravel storage directory aliasing

Tags: laravel, symfony, .htaccess, xampp, virtualhost

I am running my Laravel on XAMPP with virtualhost setup

in the httpd-vhost.conf I have added the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@.testv.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp81/htdocs/testv/public"
ServerName testv.localhost
ServerAlias www.testv.localhost
ErrorLog "logs/testv.localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/testv.localhost-access.log" common    
</VirtualHost>
```

then on httpd-xampp.conf, I added

```
Alias /storage/pub "C:/xampp81/htdocs/testv/storage/app/public/uploads"
<Directory "C:/xampp81/htdocs/testv/storage/app/public/uploads">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My intention is to make files that were uploaded in to "C:/xampp81/htdocs/testv/storage/app/public/uploads" to be accessable from the web browser via https://testv.localhost/storage/pub/image.jpg

But since I have laravel installed, accessing this url generates the error:

> [Sat Jun 03 23:36:32.880554 2023] [php:error] [pid 34700:tid 1916]
> [client ::1:63731] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member
> function send() on null in
> C:\xampp81\htdocs\testv\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:196\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> C:\xampp81\htdocs\testv\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(173):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))\n#1
> C:\xampp81\htdocs\testv\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(209):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))\n#2
> [internal function]:
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()\n#3
> {main}\n  thrown in
> C:\xampp81\htdocs\testv\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php
> on line 196, referer: https://testv.localhost/admin/tester

can someone please advice how should I fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: "to be accessable from the web browser via **https**://testv.localhost/storage/pub/image.jpg" - you've only posted the vHost for port 80 (HTTP)? But the vHost:80 you've posted is also incomplete. Either you need to be permitting access (and enabling `.htaccess` overrides I would think) OR redirecting to HTTPS. (You probably shouldn't be enabled `Indexes`, `MultiViews` and `Includes`.) Note that if you are only Apache 2.4 then you should be using `Require`, not `Order` and `Allow`. However, I don't see how this relates to the error you've posted??

Comment: well the wierd part is that if I don't use laravel, the alias works. but with laravel I get a error 500 and that line in the error log